# How to find out if there are unequal items by comparing the items of two arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to find out if there are unequal items by comparing the items of two arrays and return true or false?

```
let freeDrive = ['58:0', '58:1', '58:22'];
let filterdDrive = ['58:0', '58:1', '58:2', '58:3', '58:4', '58:5', '58:6', '58:7'];
```

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by iterating on the shorted array and check all its values, the every function is handy for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

e.g.

```
const checkInclude = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    return checkInclude (arr2, arr1)
  }
  return arr1.every(v => arr2.includes(v))
}
```

tested in chrome console

> let freeDrive = ['58:0', '58:1', '58:22'];

> let filterdDrive = ['58:0', '58:1', '58:2', '58:3', '58:4', '58:5', '58:6', '58:7'];

> checkInclude(freeDrive, filterdDrive);

> false

Comment: The problem was not solved

Comment: check the code here https://codepen.io/aSH-uncover/pen/abYRwOv - or maybe I didnt understand your problem